# VS2010 WebApp .js+.css able to be embedded fully within HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

So I'm looking to take HTML code for a slideshow and insert it into an HTML box for an app.

However, obviously the .js and .css dependencies need to go with it, or else it won't function properly.

Is there a way/program that allows me in VS to take those classes and insert them within the HTML file so that they are all read at once, and the slideshow works? Ideas?

Thanks,

D.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with visual studio, you could always embed whatever html and css you want into an HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use external files to allow the browser to cache them. Put the reference to the external files in your master page.